# How to input rounded brackets in HTML forms

Tags: html, input, frontend

I have a page with input fields. I need to input data in the format of 'something(some number)' e.g:-ABCD(123). However,upon submitting the values I see that my brackets have changed to %26 or any other number beginning with %. Is there anyway I can retain my rounded brackets after passing it through the form?

```
<form method="post">
<input type=text name="data" size=28/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's Javascript's feature, whenever a special character is processed in JS, it is replaced to respective code. In your case `(` or `)` is being replaced with `%26`, it makes sure that when you send this data to backend, then it don't cause any error.

For Eg:
In SQL Query in PHP, a `'` or `"` can cause an error in the following query if the variable have a single inverted comma.

```sh
$sql = "SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE name LIKE '{$name}'";
```

If $name = "Ankit's Shop", query will break because of `'` here.

If you print this in webpage, for example with `PHP` or `JS` on webpage,`%26` will be converted automatically to `(`/`)`.

Comment: Thankyou for the explanation. Unfortunately,since I need to perform some operations on the form field in the backend using unix script,I think there is no other way around this.

Comment: Hmm, I don't know UNIX, but there must be some 'replace' equivalent syntax in UNIX Scripts, for eg, in JS if you try replacing, ultimate output will be same, but trying in PHP with $text = str_replace("%26", ""(,  $gottext) will give required output.

Comment: It is indeed present but somehow the number assigned after % is random. It keeps on increasing like %26,%27,%28 and so on. Anyhow,thanks a lot for your help. I'll figure out a workaround.